# Can I exceed the maximum Army size by moving in more units?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Lets say I have two units at Winterfell, and two units at White Harbor. I can march from White Harbor. Can I do that with both units and march to Winterfell, and by doing so break the maximum limit of three units at Winterfell?

I haven't found any rule saying something about marching from somewhere and making a total army of, say, six or more in one area...

Answer (score 6):

No, from the [rule book](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/a_game_of_thrones_the_board_game/media/agotbgrules.pdf), on page 11:

> **The Golden Rule**: You may never move (or retreat) a unit so that it violates your current Army Supply limits (as indicated on the Supply Track). Should you do so by accident, you must immediately destroy enough units to make your armies in Supply again.

Comment: Is there a way to kill off your own units? There was a situation where a player wanted to vacate a region to prevent a second player from attacking/refilling his battle cards but I couldn't find anything that would allow this save for doing it by 'accident'.

Comment: @EvilAmarant7x, that is a different question, hich normally would require a new post, but I will give you an answer here anyway. Yes, you are allowed to march out of a region. when doing so, you can leave a token that shows that an area is controlled by your house, even though it currently is unoccupied by any of your units. Yo are incorrect in believing that it is possible to vacate a region by accident. Remember that single units are not armies, and need not be supplied. You can always have as many single units in any number of regions (wooden pieces are a limiting factor).

Comment: Ah, I didn't explain my question well as I could have. I'll make a new post.